# Using scanner input in enhanced For loop to find indexOf an object in ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm trying to take my Scanner input and use it to find the index of the location of a object/name in an ArrayList of Objects.
The code is made up of two Classes, constructor(setter/getter) and tester class
The array list was created using the following code as example;
`List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<>();`

`details.add(new Detail("Anthony", 26) );`; note i used `public void setName(String name)` and `public void setNumber(long number)` to identify the objects added to the ArrayList

The arraylist output looks like this

```
Name: Anthony   Age: 26
Name: Thomas    Age: 30
Name: Shaun Age: 29
Name: James Age: 28
```

The code below is what i'm trying to use to find the index location. This code wont compile because i dont know what to put in the parenthesis of `details.indexOf())`

```
System.out.print("Type in one of the names listed above to find index of it's location: ");
   String name = s.nextLine();
   for (Detail d : details){
    if (details.contains(s.nextLine()))
     System.out.println("The index location of " +(scanner input/name here) " is " + details.indexOf());
```

My intended output is

```
The index location of Thomas is 1
```

I Know how to get the index of an element whenit's defined into the code, id use something like `int location = details.get(2);`, i believe this would return `Name: Shaun Age: 29`, but i dont know how to take the input from the Scanner `Shaun` and return only the Location of `2`

Am I going about this in silly way? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You would have to construct a `Detail` instance and implement `equals()` for lookup. Might be simpler to do something like `IntStream.range(0, details.size()).filter(i -> contacts.get(i).getName().equals(name)).findFirst().orElse(-1)`

Comment: You can also adapt your loop to keep a running index while checking `d.getName().equals(name)`. But if you do use `indexOf()`, there's no point in the loop or checking `contains()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below approach to find the index of the name in the list.

*Here,*

1. I have iterated over the list and check the input with the names from the list, once found , assign that index and break from the loop.
2. If user input not found, then user will be notified with the message "name not found".

**Code:**

***With For loop***

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Detail> list = Arrays.asList(new Detail("Anthony",26),
                new Detail("Thomas",30),
                new Detail("Shaun",29),
                new Detail("James",28));
        System.out.print("Type in one of the names listed above to find index of it's location: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = s.nextLine();
        int index = -1;

        for(int i = 0 ;  i < list.size(); i++){
            if(name.equals(list.get(i).getName())){
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(index == -1) {
            System.out.println("name not found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The index location of " + name + " is " + index);
        }
    }
}
```

***With enhanced For loop***

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Detail> list = Arrays.asList(new Detail("Anthony",26),
                new Detail("Thomas",30),
                new Detail("Shaun",29),
                new Detail("James",28));
        System.out.print("Type in one of the names listed above to find index of it's location: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = s.nextLine();
        int index = -1;
        int counter = 0;
        for(Detail d : list){
            if(name.equals(d.getName())){
                index = counter;
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        if(index == -1) {
            System.out.println("name not found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The index location of " + name + " is " + index);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output::**

```
        Input:: Thomas
        Output:: The index location of Thomas is 1
        
        Input:: Test
        Output:: name not found
```

Comment: This looks great, but how would i do this using an enhanced for-loop
When i input ```for (Detail d : details){
                if (name.equals(details.get(i).getName())){
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
```
i get the error 
```cannot resolve the symbol 'i'```

Comment: @Donpublo With enhanced for-loop, you have to maintain one counter that will keep the index of the iterator. There is no role of index`'i'` incase of enhanced for loop .Updated the solution with both types of for loop.

Comment: For the enhanced loop, how do I not break the loop until the question until the correct input is found? My understanding is the loop should basically look like this 
```while(true){
if(input==answer) break;
else continue;
}```
to continue the loop, but i'm not sure how to implement this into the ```if``` statement string because AFAIK the loop in this comment only works for integers. I have tried modifying it to suit the enhanced loop but I can't get it to work